# Multiple input types with fold

Tags: sml, fold, ml

I am trying to figure out how to implement the fold functions on inputs of differing types. As a sample, I'll use the count function for a list (though, I have multiple functions to implement for this).
Assuming an int list input (this should work with any type of list, though), my count function would be

```
val count = foldr (fn(x:int,y)=>y+1) 0 ;
val count = fn : int list -> int
```

However, I am attempting to make a count function where the type is

```
val count = fn : int list * bool list -> int
```

where the int list is the universe of the set, and the bool determines which values of the universe are in the set. ie, (1,3,5,6),(true,false,false,true) results in a final set of (1,6), which would have a count of 2. My first thought to try this was some form of

```
val count= foldr (fn(x:(int*bool),y)=>if #2x then y+1 else y ) 0 ;
```

but this results in a return type of

```
val count = fn : (int * bool) list -> int
```

which is not quite what I need. Logically, they are similar, but I am expected to group the two types together in one list each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could use [`ListPair.foldl`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list-pair.html#SIG:LIST_PAIR.foldl:VAL):

   ```
   fun count (xs, bs) = ListPair.foldl (fn (x, b, acc) => ...) ... (xs, bs)
   ```

   where the first `...` is some combination of `x`, `b` and `acc` and the second `...` is the initial value.

   This assumes that `xs` and `bs` are equally long, and in case they're not, discards the remaining elements in the longer list. (You should probably try to justify if this gives the correct answer in either case `xs` or `bs` is longer.)
2. Otherwise, you need to combine (aka zip) your *int list × bool list* into an *(int × bool) list* by making a function that combines two lists, and use this function in combination with the folding you are already doing.

   ```
   fun combine (x::xs, y::ys) = ...
     | combine (..., ...) = ...
   ```

   This function could be equivalent to `ListPair.zip`.